# カスタマイズした404.htmlが反映されない

Tags: python, python3, django

お世話になります。以下にご質問させてください。
djangoのバージョンは3.1.7です。

#### 達成したいこと

404エラーとなる際にカスタマイズした404.htmlが表示されるようにしたい。

#### これまでに実施した内容

- views.py にて `get_object_or_404` で404エラーを返すようにしている。
- ルートディレクトリ内に新しくtemplatesを作成。その中に404.htmlを作成。
- settings.py に `import os` を追記（"os is not defined." となるため）
- settings.py - TEMPLATES - 'DIRS' に `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` を追加

#### 上記内容の実施結果

デフォルトの404エラーのページが表示されるのみ。
カスタマイズした404のページが表示されない。

Answer (score 0):

Windows10のdjango 3.1.7上で、末尾のpowershellスクリプトを実行して動作確認したところ、正しくカスタム404が表示されました。
下記の設定にお間違えがないかをご確認ください。

- `manage.py`と同階層に`templates`フォルダを作っている
- `settings.py`を`DEBUG = False`に切り替えている
  (デバッグモードでは強制的に詳細なエラーメッセージが[表示されます](https://djangobrothers.com/blogs/django_404_page/))

※手順が冗長になるので割愛しましたが、[polls.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/3.1/intro/tutorial02/)を作成して`get_object_or_404`を呼び出しても設定を間違えなければカスタム404が表示されることを確認しました。

powershellスクリプト:

```
# C:\django にプロジェクトページを新規作成
$django = "C:\django" 
if(-not (Test-Path $django)) { mkdir $django }
cd $django
#rm -r mysite
django-admin startproject mysite

# テンプレート作成
cd $django\mysite\
mkdir templates
"Hello 404." | Out-File ".\templates\404.html" -Encoding default

# settings.pyを置換
cd .\mysite\
$settings = Get-Content settings.py
$settings = $settings -replace "'DIRS': \[\],", "'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]," 
$settings = $settings -replace "import Path", "import Path`r`nimport os" 
# デバッグモードでは 404.html を読みこまないので本番モードに変更
$settings = $settings -replace "DEBUG = True", "DEBUG = False" 
$settings = $settings -replace "ALLOWED_HOSTS = \[\]", "ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']" 
# 上書き保存
$settings | Out-File ".\settings.py" -Encoding default

# 実行
cd $django\mysite\
start "python" -ArgumentList "manage.py", "runserver" -PassThru
start "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/"
```